# Can I use an SQL query inside code for Isotope

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-isotope

I would like to just say thank you in advance.

I'm very new to using SQL and I've been working on a project involving a database of about 3000 items.

I'm currently using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and don't know how to proceed.

1. Is it possible to call a query into a .PHP for isotope to reference?

If I have 3000 items like this in a .PHP
The Data-category, Link, Name, and possibly other data would be pulled from the database and formatted like this for Isotope to sort them
Ex.

```
<div class="Container" data-category="Genre" onclick="SELECT ShowLink, FROM ShowList;">
    <h3 class="name">ShowTitle</h3>
  </div>
```

2. I have a feeling this would be a taboo but I'm looking for the best way to assimilate a database of shows and episodes into this format for Isotope to sort them. Is there a better way?

If there's any other information I can provide that would be of assistance, I will keep an eye on this post to keep it updated.

Comment: That's almost like giving your users access to your phpmyadmin interface ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create seperate php file for processing query.

```
<div class="Container" data-category="Genre">
  <a href="show.php">
     <h3 class="name">ShowTitle</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

And put the query inside **show.php**

```
<?php
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT ShowLink FROM ShowList");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['ShowLink'];
 } 
?>
```

Apply any design layout to echoing output from query.